# Plain Text Uploaded to Firebase Storage Gets Converted to ASCII Numbers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

When I upload plain text to firebase storage, the result that ultimately gets uploaded is not the plain text that I submitted, but instead, a string of numbers that correspond to ASCII characters.

I followed [the example from the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) almost exactly, here is my code:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("example.txt");
const message = "This is my message.";
storageRef.putString(message);
```

However, when I check the file on the server, I find that it contains the following:

> 84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,109,121,32,109,101,115,115,97,103,101,46

I have also tried this code:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("example.txt");
const message = "This is my message.";
storageRef.putString(message, "raw", { contentType: "text/plain" });
```

But it doesn't make a difference.

I am running this from a react native expo managed workflow, using the firebase js sdk (I just ran expo install firebase).

Can anyone tell me why my data is getting converted to ASCII, how I can prevent that from happening, or how I can otherwise resolve this?

Comment: How are you checking your file? I just tried uploading a file like this: `storageRef.putString(message, "raw", { contentType: "text/plain" })` and it definitely worked.

Comment: I downloaded it from the console and opened it up in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is the result of a Firebase bug, but I found a workaround by creating a blob and using "put" instead of "putString"

E.g.

```
const obj = {hello: 'world'};
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {type : 'application/json'});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("example.json");
storageRef.put(blob)
```

Still having a little trouble figuring out how to do this for images though...

Comment: Does this works? It does not work for me